# Gremlin JavaAPI vs Gremlin-Server?

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

1. Use `gremlin` `java` api directly in my application
2. Deploy a `gremlin-server`, use `gremlin-driver` api, connect to `gremlin-server`

Which one is better? Or what is the the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today, the answer depends on your environment to some degree. If you ever intend to use a non-jvm language (python, C#, js, etc), then you should likely use Gremlin Server as that will be the only way to build your application. If you want to be in the best position to switch to other graph databases and away from the one you've currently chosen, then using Gremlin Server might be better as not all graph databases are available through the direct Java API (there are at least two, that embed Gremlin Server and only allow connection via driver).

So, if the answer to those two questions are a resounding "no", then I don't think I could convince you to include Gremlin Server in your application, especially if you don't have a terribly complex project to worry about. It's adding another layer to your architecture that you would probably prefer to avoid.

If you do choose to embed, then be sure to use the Traversal API over the Structure API. Recall that the Structure API is meant for graph providers implementing the TinkerPop interfaces for their graph system. In other words, for this code:

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()
```

prefer use of the API provided by `g` over the one provided by `graph` for querying and mutating the graph.

I do believe however that TinkerPop's future does have a solid dependence on "Gremlin Server" (the future incarnation may look different, but would be a "server component" of some sort) as something that will be less of a question to users to include. It would be great to see this decision point removed and simplified.